# How to insert HTML code into HTML file from a .gs using Google Apps Script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-apps

My variables I'm inserting into an HTML file using the code below inserts the variables as plaintext and does not register code within my variables.

```
function sendEmail(){
var htmlBody = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('emailFormat');
var variableOne = "text";

htmlBody.example = '<p>' + variableOne + '</p>';

var email_html = htmlBody.evaluate().getContent();

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "email@email.com",
    subject: "subject",
    htmlBody: email_html
  });
}
```

The code above makes anywhere I put `<?= example ?>` within the file 'emailFormat' become `"<p>text</p>"`. The problem is it does not display it as "text" it displays `"<p>text</p>"` entirely. How do I get it to show register the `<p>'s` as code?

Comment: Show your html code

Answer (score 7):

The tags `<?= ?>` will [escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) the output, thus `<?= <p> ?>` will "print" the string `<p>` and not a paragraph tag.

You can use `<?!= ?>` to *not* escape the output.  Those are useful for [including](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices) additional HTML and inline JavaScript, CSS files into your templates.  Using the exclamation mark should fix your issue.

But in your case, try just putting the `<p>` tags outside `<?= =?>` tags like this:

```html
<p><?= example ?></p>
```

That's the typical way to do it. Or if you need to switch the tags, you could use the `<?!=` option, but that puts HTML in your JavaScript... it's a subjective choice, but you can also control options by using the `<? ?>` tags like this:

Code.gs

```js
// html refers to a template
html.type = "p";
html.content = "some paragraph content!";
```

template.html

```html
<? if (type === "p") { ?>
<p> <?= content ?> </p>
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function sendEmail(){
  var v1="Hello World";
  var html='<p>' + v1 + '</p>';
  MailApp.sendEmail({to: "email@email.com", subject: "Email Test", htmlBody: html});

}
```

We don't really load html into html files from gs file scripts except possibly via the Google Apps Script Advanced API.  We can however load html directly into the Document Object Model of a browser by using [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) and then it's just a matter of getting the element by id and loading it's text or innerHTML via Javascript.  I don't think even scriplets actually load it into the html file but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Scriptlets do load in, I use it for other variables that are just text.